# Is there any well-known holographic duality that allows wormholes and CTCs to exist?

Tags: general-relativity, ads-cft, holographic-principle, wormholes, closed-timelike-curve

Is there any well-known holographic duality (like AdS/CFT or holographic principle in string theory/black holes) that contains wormholes and Closed Timelike Curves?

I was discussing this with a physicist and he told me:

> Certainly, to whatever extent you take AdS/CFT seriously as a guide to the real world, quantum gravity is dual to a perfectly ordinary conformal field theory on a fixed background, and therefore tachyons, wormholes, and, therefore, hypercomputation should presumably not be possible

Is he right? Are there any other well-known holographic duality/model that allows wormholes and CTCs to exist?

I've been told about ER/EPR, but is it there any other type of duality that would also allow wormholes, CTC (and thus, hypercomputation) to exist? Would any type of AdS/CFT or dS/CFT models (for example) or any other type of well-known holographic system allow this (apart from ER/EPR)? Any other holographic duality (apart from ER/EPR) that would basically propose a "hypercomputer-universe" model?

Comment: You may want to look up the ER=EPR business

Comment: @Slereah thank you very much!! Is there any other type of duality that would also allow wormholes, CTC (and thus, hypercomputation) to exist? Would any type of AdS/CFT or dS/CFT models (for example) or any other type of well-known holographic system allow this (apart from ER/EPR)? Any other holographic duality (apart from ER/EPR) that would basically propose a "hypercomputer-universe" model?